# Inverting all 32 bits in a number using binary operators in c#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, 32-bit, binary-operators

I am wondering how you take a number (for example 9), convert it to a 32 int (00000000000000000000000000001001), then invert or flip every bit (11111111111111111111111111110110) so that the zeroes become ones and the ones become zeroes.

I know how to do that by replacing the numbers in a string, but I need to know how to do that with binary operators on a binary number.

I think you have to use this operator, "~", but it just gives me a negative number when I use it on a value.

Comment: use an unsigned int.

Comment: `11111111111111111111111111110110` as an `int` ***is*** a negative number; `~val` is correct; if you din't want it signed, use `uint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the decimal version of your number then its a negative number.
If you declare it as a unsigned int then its a positive one.
But this doesnt matter, binary it will always be 11111111111111111111111111110110.
Try this:

```
int number = 9;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(number, 2)); //Gives you 1001
number = ~number;                               //Invert all bits
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(number, 2));
//Gives you  your wanted result: 11111111111111111111111111110110
```

Answer (score 2):

That is doing the correct functionality. The `int` data type within C# uses signed integers, so 11111111111111111111111111110110 is in fact a negative number.

As Marc pointed out, if you want to use unsigned values declare your number as a `uint`.

Comment: it isn't really true (or at least: complete) to say "C# uses signed integers"; more correctly, C# makes it readily available to use either signed (`sbyte`, `short`, `int`, `long`) or unsigned (`byte`, `ushort`, `uint`, `ulong`) integers

Comment: @MarcGravell True, I meant int.